# What runs faster in Ruby: defining the alias method or using alias_method?

Tags: ruby, performance

What is faster on later invocation:

```
def first_method?() second_method?() end
```

or

```
alias_method :first method, :second_method
```

and if possible why?

(NOTE: I don't ask what is nicer / better etc. -> only raw speed and why it is faster is interesting here)

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the first version has one additional method lookup to do? Rubinius does simplify some code so it could be identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a quick look at the source code, will show you the trick:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.src/M000447.html

alias_method is written in C. moreover, defining a method in ruby that calls another method, will result in 2 method lookups and calls.

so, alias_method should be faster.

Comment: Yes, but the implementation (in C) of `alias_method` does not really matter (unless I misunderstood the question). The point is that apparently `alias_method` just creates another entry in the symbol table referring to the original function object. And this cannot be seen from the linked source.

Comment: that's not the main point. not only it creates an entry in the symbol table, but it says that it should return the result of the aliased method. this is completely different from defining (with ruby) a method that explicitly calls another.

Comment: @Andrea Pavoni: That's what I meant. But how is this obvious from http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.src/M000447.html?

Comment: that's what rb_alias does, check its definition in <ruby_sources>/eval.c

Answer (score 13):

At least in Ruby 1.8.6, aliasing seems to be faster:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

require 'benchmark'

$global_bool = true

class Object 
  def first_method?
    $global_bool
  end

  def second_method?
    first_method?
  end 

  alias_method :third_method?, :first_method?
end

Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("first:")  { 1000000.times { first_method?  }}
  x.report("second:") { 1000000.times { second_method? }}
  x.report("third:")  { 1000000.times { third_method?  }}
end
```

results in :

```
$ ./test.rb
             user     system      total        real
first:   0.281000   0.000000   0.281000 (  0.282000)
second:  0.469000   0.000000   0.469000 (  0.468000)
third:   0.281000   0.000000   0.281000 (  0.282000)
```

Obviously, you have one method call less (look-up receiver ...). So it seems natural for it to be faster.

Comment: I've done a similar benchmark and it seems to confirm what you're saying. It's fair enough to say aliasing would be a bit faster...

Comment: just want to add that performance of `alias` is similar to `alias_method`